# Executing cURL command in R

Tags: r, curl, twitter

I am using the Twitter REST API to retrieve data in JSON format.  Twitter's developer page makes it easy by providing a command that can be pasted directly into the terminal and executed.  The following command works in the terminal.

```
 curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'count=3200&screen_name=BernieSanders' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="####", oauth_nonce="####", oauth_signature="####", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1467719924", oauth_token="####", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

I am trying to get the JSON data into R, and would like to execute this same command in the R console.  I have tried `curlconverter` using the exact same code, get an error that there is an unexpected symbol.  However, the code is exactly the same.  Is there a more suitable package for executing this code?

```
curlExample <- "curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'count=3200&screen_name=BernieSanders' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="####", oauth_nonce="####", oauth_signature="####", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1467719924", oauth_token="####", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to need to escape those quotation marks.  Try this instead:

```
curlExample <- "curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'count=3200&screen_name=BernieSanders' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"####\", oauth_nonce=\"####\", oauth_signature=\"####\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1467719924\", oauth_token=\"####\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"' --verbose"
```

That the quotes were not being escaped properly was actually evident in your question, because the Stack Overflow markup rendered the `curlExample` string in multiple colors.

Comment: You need to investigate the RCurl package.  I assumed you had everything else working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf is the way to do this in R.

But specifically in your case, you have unescaped " in your string.